# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soapui

I am trying to consume below public web service using Eclipse. 
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl

When I execute in the java client it gives the error;

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Below is the simple client program;

```
public class ClientTest1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GlobalWeatherSoapProxy obj1 = new GlobalWeatherSoapProxy();
        try
        {
            System.out.println(obj1.getCitiesByCountry("Japan"));
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            System.out.println(+e1.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

However strangely this works fine when consumed through SOAP UI. Hence I assume this is something to do with Eclipse configuration.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: How did you generate the classes from wsdl? cxf, jax-ws?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has nothing to do with it. Your code is executed by the JVM, even if your development environment is Eclipse. A connection time out means that your client is not able to connect with the endpoint.

You have auto-generated the client proxy in some way getting `GlobalWeatherSoapProxy`. This class will obtain the reference to endpoint by  loading WSDL. Alternatively url can be provided by code. Review the content of that class to see how endpoint URL is loaded

You should see something like (check this full [example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/))

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl");
QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mkyong.com/", "HelloWorldImplService");
Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);
```